# How to get data saved in other view?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, load, nsuserdefaults

I have been struggling with that for some time. I have a tab bar application. In `SecondView` I define number2 and save it to `NSUserDefaults` as I want it to be remembered by the program at the next time the app is open. In the `FirstView` I want to do some calculation (and display the answer) that include number2 saved earlier. I can't get it working. In the code, I left only things that are working so far. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UILabel *labelAnswer;
}
-(IBAction)buttonCalc;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *labelAnswer;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize labelAnswer;

-(IBAction)buttonCalc {
    float number1 = 2;

//what should I put here (or somewhere else) to get number2 saved in second view?

    float answer = number1;// + number2
    labelAnswer.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", answer];
}
```

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *textNumber2;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults;
}

-(IBAction)buttonSave;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textNumber2;
@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize textNumber2;

-(IBAction)buttonSave {
    //saving my data
    NSString *saveNumber2 = textNumber2.text;
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:saveNumber2 forKey:@"savedNumber2"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //loading my data
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadNumber2 = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedNumber2"];
    [textNumber2 setText:loadNumber2];
}
```

Comment: in this method -(IBAction)buttonCalc  you want to calculate number1 and number2? am i right.

Comment: In buttonCalc I want to calculate a sum of number1 and number2 which is saved somewhere else (define in another tab view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try following code in your method hope it will help you...

```
-(IBAction)buttonCalc {
    float number1 = 2;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *strNumber2 = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedNumber2"];

    float number2 = [strNumber2 floatValue];

//what should I put here (or somewhere else) to get number2 saved in second view?

    float answer = number1 + number2; 
    labelAnswer.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", answer];
}
```

Comment: That'it! I think I tried it before but it didn't work. Thanks mate!

Comment: whats problem you have to face?

Comment: this is not use then you can take one float variable in appdelegate and set value in button click in secondview and use that in first view it is better

Comment: Yes, I know. But there was a reason for that. The second number is settings value and it is in another view. Anyway, I messed up with the code a bit. This is my first project and I want to learn as much as possible before I release some killer apps. ;)

Answer (score 1):

user this , it may help you

```
-(IBAction)buttonCalc {
    float number1 = 2;

//what should I put here (or somewhere else) to get number2 saved in second view?

   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSString *loadNumber2 = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedNumber2"]; 
  NSInteger number2=[loadNumber2 integerValue];
   float answer = number1 + number2;
    labelAnswer.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", answer];
}
```